# Add csv in cassandra

Tags: csv, cassandra, putty

How can I add .csv files from my local storage to Cassandra(running on AWS server) using puTTY.

I am trying this but it gives me an error saying "cant open. No matching path found" (even though the file is present in that location)

```
copy tableName (col1, col2,col3) from 'C:\Users\TEST.csv' with HEADER = true ;
```

Comment: Are you running Cassandra on your windows machine? What putty has to do with Cassandra and the copy command?

Comment: cassandra is running on ec2 which I access through puTTY. Anyways I figured out how it works. Thanks Mr. @Horia

Answer (score -2):

The .csv file first has to be on an FTP application(example FileZilla) before uploading it to Cassandra while using puTTY.